# Bash while command

Tags: bash, menu, while-loop

I have created a bash menu script, using options 1-8. For my second menu option I am using the `while` command to display the current time and date. However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to end the display of the date it jumps out of the entire script rather than redisplay the menu. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why don't you add your code to the question? Without the code, no one can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, make functions

```
#more code here ...
    display_main_menu() {
    while true; do

            echo -e "Please select an action:"
        echo -e " "
        echo -e "1 - Transfer a local file to all servers."
        echo -e "2 - Execute a command(s) on all servers."
        echo -e "9 - Display all servers."
        echo -e "0 - Exit"
        echo ""
            read -p "" action

        case $action in
            "1" ) function_to_transfer_file ;;
        "2" ) function_to_execute_command ;;
            "9" ) function_to_show_server;;
            "0" ) exit;;
            * ) echo "Please select a valid action.";;
        esac
    done
    }

#more code here ...
```

Make multiple functions, one for each option in primary menu. Here option 0 exits the script completely.

For secondary menu functions ... option 0 should execute function `display_main_menu`

Comment: So would  display_main_menu() be repeated after the option with the while command? - Apologies, I am new to this.

Comment: give me the options you want from the  main menu and secondary menu, so I can understand

Answer (score 0):

You want catch the signal SIGINT (Ctrl+C) and break

```
trap 'break' SIGINT
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash 

trap 'break' SIGINT 
while : 
do 
    sleep 1 
    echo "foo" 
done 
echo "bar"
```

Take a look here to have more details:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_12.html

```
#!/bin/bash 
#more code here ... 
    display_main_menu() { 
    while true; do 

        echo -e "Please select an action:" 
        echo -e " " 
        echo -e "1 - display time" 
        echo -e "2 - Execute a command(s) on all servers." 
        echo -e "9 - Display all servers." 
        echo -e "0 - Exit" 
        echo "" 
            read -p "" action 

        case $action in 
            "1" ) trap 'break' SIGINT; while true; do echo "$(date '+%D %T' )"; sleep 1; done ;; 
            "2" ) function_to_execute_command ;; 
            "9" ) function_to_show_server;; 
            "0" ) exit;; 
            * ) echo "Please select a valid action.";; 
        esac 
    done 
    } 

    display_main_menu
```

Comment: Will that then redisplay the menu option?

Comment: I don't know, I just explain you how to catch Ctrl+C to break a loop.
Without your code I cannot answer

Comment: #display the menu 
echo ".........................."
echo "     My Menu  "
echo ".........................."
echo "Option 1"
echo "Option 2"
echo "Option 3"
etc 


2) 
#colored time and date ... Ctrl+C to end this 
while true; do echo "$(date '+%D %T' | toilet -f term -F border --gay)"; sleep 1; done
;;

Comment: Update with full example